# What regex can I use to split a string into words but keep phrases in round brackets together?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to split a string like this:

```
my_string = "I want to split this (these should stay together) correctly"
```

and have the following result:

```
["I", "want", "to", "split", "this", "(these should stay together)", "correctly"]
```

I tried this:

```
my_string.split(/(?=[^\(]){1,} (?=[^\)]){1,}/)
```

But the elements inside the round brackets get separated. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If the string were `"x((x)x"` would you want `["x", "((x)", " x"]` or `["x", "(", "(x)", " x"]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split` is the wrong tool here. Use `scan`.

```
my_string.scan(/\([^)]*\)|\S+/)
# => ["I", "want", "to", "split", "this", "(these should stay together)", "correctly"]
```

If the balanced parentheses can be adjacent to other non-space characters, which you want to put together, then you might want this one, which works more generally:

```
my_string.scan(/(?:\([^)]*\)|\S)+/)
```

In general, when the delimiters can be expressed in a simple pattern, use `split`. When the content can be expressed in a simple pattern, use `scan`.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that FSM will try or-matchers in the same order as they listed?

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes. The order is important.

Comment: This will return unexpected (IMHO) result on nested parenthesis.

Comment: @mudasobwa Correct. I assumed that is not the case. With a bit more complicated regex, it is possible to capture nested parentheses.

Comment: I don't have nested parentheses in my case so that is ok

Answer (score 2):

It may be desirable to do it in two steps, to keep the regex simple:

```
first, middle, last = my_string.partition /\(.*\)/
[*first.split, middle, *last.split]
  #=> ["I", "want", "to", "split", "this", "(these should stay together)",
  #    "correctly"]
```

Another example:

```
first, middle, last = "x (x(x(x)x)x) x".partition /\(.*\)/
[*first.split, middle, *last.split]
  #=> ["x", "(x(x(x)x)x)", x"]
```

But it fails here:

```
first, middle, last = "x (x)x(x) x".partition /\(.*\)/
[*first.split, middle, *last.split]
  #=> [ "x, "(x)x(x)", "x"]
```

assuming `["x", "(x)", "x", "(x)", "x"]` is desired.

Comment: This works, but is bound to this very specific example (i.e., there can be only one balanced parentheses). But you are right. Doing it in multiple steps can make the regex simpler.

Comment: Actually, using the fact that `split` can capture both the delimiters as well as the substrings in between, and using `each_cons(2)`, you can generalize your line of answer to allow arbitrary number of balanced parentheses.

Comment: @sawa, doesn't the fact that `.*` is greedy address your concern? I may be missing your point. An example of a problematic string?

Comment: Right. You have to fix that part either using `[^)]` or non-greedy.

Comment: A problematic string to your code is `"foo bar (a b) baz (c d) foo"`.

Comment: @sawa: I see (at last)! Mulling.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of curiosity:

```
my_string.gsub(/\(.+?\)/) { |m| m.gsub ' ', ' ' }.split(/ +/)
```

Try to copy-paste the code above into IRB and stay tuned:

```
#⇒ ["I", "want", "to", "split", "this", 
#   "(these should stay together)", "correctly"]
```

:)

**NB** This is a joke, please, do not use this in production.

As @sawa suggested, it is kinda escaping, so, to make this answer correct, one should convert back everything to normal spaces:

```
    my_string.gsub(/\(.+?\)/) { |m| m.gsub ' ', ' ' }
             .split(/ +/)
             .gsub ' ', ' '
```

Comment: I don't know what `m.gsub ' ', ' '` is doing. But it works. Is one of them a tab or some non-ASCII space?

Comment: Of course it works, but you should not in fact upvote this answer. It is cheating with nbsp. ASCII-8 non-breakable space, yes.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach. Seriously. Why do you comment not to use it? It is a very clean idea. The idea can be regarded as some sort of escaping.

Comment: @sawa Then I should at least convert these spaces back. I will update an answer.

Comment: You can use something visible (but rarely used in ordinary text) to make it more understandable.

Comment: I posted this answer as a joke. You were surprised for a couple of seconds, right?

Comment: Yes, but after a few seconds, I guessed what you did. And seriously, this approach is very clean. But if you don't want to, I will not push you any more to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` using this regex:

```
/ +(?![^()]*\))/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hM4aR0/3)

i.e.

```
my_string.split(/ +(?![^()]*\))/)
```

`(?![^()]*\))` is **negative lookahead** that means don't match a space if it is followed by a 0 or more non-parentheses characters followed by a right parenthesis thus not matching spaces inside `(...)`.